# Adding a record does not auto update page number will paginate

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I am on a page where i list the records(using will_paginate) and also add a new record. When i add a record, the list is updated with the new record. But the pagination does not get updated. I used ryanbates episode 134 for listing records and adding records the ajax way.

For example: I have 5 records on the list page, when i add the 6th record, the list is updated
with the new record, but the pagination is not updated to show that there are 2 pages.

Comment: do you see 6 records on one page after adding new record?

Comment: @IvanDenisov,I have my jquery written in such a way that the latest record shows on the top and hence the last record is hidden and without pagination.

Comment: @Kumar when you add/remove records on the client via AJAX the pagination won't change because the logic for that is on the server: `will_paginate` conjurs up some static HTML for rendering.  if you stop using AJAX to add records it will work as expected.  your other option is to move the pagination into the client with javascript.